# how can I implement excel like VLOOKUP if the index I'm looking for is a combination of a column vector and the row headlines?

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to to re-organize a data set which is showing Household information across multiple parameters. I need to reorganize the data as the some of the data (coordinates) are duplicated in the column vector.

I'm not able to setup an empty data frame that I can then fill with the correct function to pull the data from my initial data set. I would want to have the coordinates either as row names or as the first vector in the df_new data set (I'm not sure what would be best for this scenario). The age groups would be the names of the columns. But now I do not have the index itself in the df_new (which I would use with the merge function to get the data from df). I would need to create the index by concatenating the row name (or first vector in data set) with the column name to create the index. Since concatenating would create the unique index I hope I would be able to pull the reference number from the initial dataset to the new one (represented as NA in the sample code).

```
column_vector <- c("50", "50", " 50")
row_vector_1 <- c("Age_10","Age_15","Age_20")
row_vector_2 <- c("6","3","2")
df <- data.frame(column_vector, row_vector_1, row_vector_2)
df
colnames(df)<- c("Coordinates", "Age_indicator", "reference_NR")
df$index <- paste(df$Coordinates, df$Age_indicator, sep = "_")
df_new <- data.frame(c(50, 51, 52), c("NA", "NA", "NA"), c("NA", "NA", "NA"))
colnames(df_new) <- c( "Coordinates", "Age_10", "Age_15")
df_new
```

at the end it df_new should look like this :

[image]

The 6 and 4 where pulled from the initial df. 2nd and 3rd row are NA because their coordinates where not specified in the df. I would want them to be also populated with their respective reference_NR

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: for df_new the first row string would be 50, 6, 3 (sorry wanted to post the table from R directly but it doesn't diplay well in this comment field). the 6 and 3 are from the df table. I hope this helps

Comment: Try `dcast()` function in reshape2 package.

Comment: thank you so much, I was looking for a solution for quite some time, turns out it was as easy as this!